# ГрЕнки или гренкИ?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударение: "грЕнки" или "гренкИ"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно "гренкИ", потому что единственное число - не "гренка", как говорят многие, а "гренок". Правда, первая версия в просторечии прижилась прочнее.

Answer (score 3):

В словарях не сказано, что "грЕнки" — просторечие. Мало того, в словаре "Русское словесное ударение" "[грЕнки](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&word=%E3%F0%E5%ED%EA%E8)" — единственный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

**гренОк**
Орфографический словарь, проф.Д.Н.Ушаков, **1938**

**гренОк**, -нкА
Орфографический словарь русского языка под ред.С.И.Ожегова и А.Б.Шапиро, **1957**

**грЕнки**, -нок, *ед*. грЕнка, -и
и
**гренкИ,**  -Ов, *ед.* гренОк, -нкА
Орфографический словарь русского языка, В.В.Бурцева, **2003**

*Любой язык имеет тенденцию **развиваться-изменяться со временем:***
то, что было **однозначно правильным 60 - 80 лет назад,**  сейчас имеет право на двойную интерпретацию.

Answer (score 1):

Словари дают по-разному, вернее всего считать правильным гренОк-гренкИ как нормативную форму и грЕнка-грЕнки как разговорную. Последняя активно вытесняет историческую.

Answer (score 1):

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8#cite_note-1) пишет:

*В различных словарях приводится разное ударение. Согласно словарю «Русское словесное ударение» М. В. Зарвы 2001 г. издания ударение падает на первый слог, в то время как «Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук» (отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин), «Толковый словарь русского языка» Ожегова и Шведовой 1992 г. издания и «Большой толковый словарь» Кузнецова в редакции 2009 г. допускают оба варианта ударения, приводя ударение на второй слог в качестве первого варианта.*

Орфографический словарь и Большой толковый словарь на [Грамоте.Ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) дают оба варианта **гренка-гренки и гренок-гренки.**

А в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) четко указано ударение:

***грен-ки́***
форма именительного и винительного падежа множественного числа существительного грено́к

***гре́н-ки***
разг. форма именительного и винительного падежа множественного числа существительного гре́нка

Answer (score 1):

Нормативно и литературно: ГренОк — ед. число, ГренкИ — мн. число (см. орфоэпические словари - там отражается норма именно произношения).

Иные, разговорные варианты, допустимы в просторечии. Но уровень грамотности населения при современном уровне образования так низок, что, весьма возможно, скоро все просторечные варианты вытеснят нормативные.
И будем говорить, как безграмотные люмпены: свеклА, морквА, стЮдень, желаНтин...

При нынешнем уровне культуры ненормативная лексика  многих уже не шокирует.

Comment: Давайте не будем углубляться в уровень чужой грамотности. Не об этом вопрос, каждый может ошибаться. А насчет словарей - говорите конкретно. Словари разные бывают. Аванесов отражает норму полувековой давности, Зарва ориетирован на работников СМИ (одна норма, без вариантов, даже допустимых), Еськова (2015), кажется, уже допускает - её нет в сети, по памяти - грЕнка и грЕнки.

Comment: Будьте добры, приведите названия конкретных источников.