# ГрЕнки или гренкИ?

Tags: орфоэпия

Не перестаю открывать для себя что-то новое в русском языке. В книге Г. А. Крылова "Словарь ошибок русского языка" есть статья, посвященная этому слову. Автор утверждает, что единственным нормативным вариантом является *гренкИ* (мн. число) и *гренОк* (ед. число, муж. род). Действительно ли так говорят в повседневной жизни (никогда не слышала раньше)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ГренкИ - старая норма, грЕнки - новая. На сегодняшний день некоторые словари дают оба варианта как нормативные, некоторые, например словарь Зарвы, только грЕнки. Поэтому можете не переучиваться.

Answer (score 2):

Было уже. [Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/701/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8). И [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Вопрос задаётся с пугающей регулярностью.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо! Извините, что "напугала" в очередной раз) Похоже, это бунт народа против литературной нормы)

Comment: Да без проблем. Просто модераторы не любят повторяющихся вопросов.

Comment: @behemothus, а про "ступнИ" и "стУпни" тоже было? мне нравится первый вариант, но некоторые считают его неравильным...

Comment: Не помню такого.
По сути: ни разу не видел словаря, где бы стУпни считалось бы допустимым. Хотя тут, конечно, есть над чем подумать.